# How to copy and paste as plain text on iOS?

Tags: ios, copy-paste

Currently my workaround is to paste the text in the Notes app and copy from there the plain text to paste it to, for example the Mail app.

How can I copy formatted text and paste it as plain text, for example in the Mail app?

Answer (score 42):

At least from iOS 13 onwards, the following copies without formatting:

1. Select the text.
2. From the pop-up bubble, don't tap "Copy" but instead tap "Share...".
3. From the share sheet, tap "Copy".

This copies without formatting, at least in Safari, Mail and probably many other apps.

Answer (score 15):

I use the "Share > Copy" trick:

1. Paste formatted.
2. Select the just pasted text and in the context menu swipe right and tap on "Share...".
3. In the Share sheet, tap on "Copy". This copies as plain text!
4. Tap still selected text to get the context menu again.
5. In the context menu tap on "Paste" to replace the selected, formatted text with its plain text representation.

Still (too) many hoops to jump through but at least you don't need to switch between apps.

Answer (score 8):

On iPadOS 13.4.1, I just tested <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>  and it will paste without formatting.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a workaround that worked for me:

1. Go to Safari.
2. Paste the formatted text in the address field.
3. Select the text and copy again.

Now the formatting should be stripped away.