# How do I cut-and-paste plain text from Notes to another iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, gmail

If I draft an email message in emacs and then cut-and-paste it to the gmail web app, the text looks fine. Only plain text gets copied.

But if I use iOS Notes to draft the message on an iPhone (what else do you use to draft?) and then cut-and-paste the message to the gmail iOS app (you agree it's more convenient then using the gmail web app on an iPhone, no?), then some kind of rich-text gets copied, with the result of sending text in a *much* larger font.

How do I cut-and-paste plain text from Notes to another iOS app?

Related:

- The problem apparently [occurs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/357429/7985) for those using Notes to draft on macOS.
- Someone sought the [opposite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/354992/7985) (pasting rich-text). I'm not sure why that was not the default for them.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the formatting, copy the data to a coding app like iEditor from iEditor copy the data and paste to where you need it. 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ieditor-text-code-editor/id562162723?mt=8

To avoid the double copy, work in iEditor. I do this all the time on macOS.

Copy and paste involves how the "copy" app and the "paste" app handling the text. The copy app may make several formats of the data available. One format must be a styled version. Another will likely be a text only version.  The "paste" app is free to select any of the formats.

What I do on macos, when the "copy" app is passing formatted data that I do not want, is to copy the data to a coding editor.  The coding edit will pick the data form without any styling information.  You end up with plan text.  I then copy and paste into the destination app.